# django password reset password_reset_confirm

Tags: python, django

I am doing a project in django. In my project I required to reset my password through email. For that I used  django.contrib.auth.urls. My test was successful when passed through the djangos template.Later I tried it on my template, for that I created a registration folder and created the five html pages including the email template. Also I included `url(r'^web/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`, in my main url. But when I run the server I could pass the link to the email. And open the view in my browser. In that I changed my password which is entered twice and when I submit nothing happened what is the problem please help me ?

**my password_reset_confirm.html is**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    {% if validlink %}
        <p>Please enter your new password twice.<br />
           So we can verify you typed it in correctly.</p>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div style="display:none">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}"name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
            </div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.new_password1.errors }}
                        <label for="id_new_password1">New password:</label></td>
                    <td>{{ form.new_password1 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ form.new_password2.errors }}
                        <label for="id_new_password2">Confirm password:</label></td>
                    <td>{{ form.new_password2 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Change my password" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        <h1>Password reset unsuccessful</h1>
        <p>The password reset link was invalid, <br />
        possibly because it has already been used. <br />
        Please request a new password reset.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented the password reset procedure with a bit different way, the bellow has been tested and works:

in project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^user/', include('users.urls')),
)
```

in urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^password-reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', kwargs={'template_name': 'password_reset_form.html'}, name='password-reset'),
url(r'^password_reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', kwargs={'template_name': 'password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',kwargs={'template_name': 'password_reset_confirm.html'},name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete', kwargs={'template_name': 'password_reset_complete.html'}, name='password_reset_complete'),
...
```

For my convinience I created the template files under the root directory of the app, the above urls are under /user of my project.

```
users/templates$ ls password*
password_reset_complete.html  password_reset_done.html
password_reset_confirm.html   password_reset_form.html
```

I tested and its working, forms are the same as the django provided one, only I extend my frontpage base template, since I don't want any django admin templates appearing to the front end users, for example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans 'Password reset' %}{% endblock %}

{% block maincontent %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        {% if validlink %}
        <h1>{% trans 'Enter new password' %}</h1>
        <p>{% trans "Please enter your new password twice so we can verify you typed it in correctly." %}</p>

        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.new_password1.errors }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_new_password1">{% trans 'New password:' %}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" id="id_new_password1" name="new_password1" value="">
            </p>
            {{ form.new_password2.errors }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_new_password2">{% trans 'Confirm password:' %}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" id="id_new_password2" name="new_password2" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-l2">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="{% trans 'Change my password' %}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        {% else %}

        <h1>{% trans 'Password reset unsuccessful' %}</h1>

        <p>{% trans "The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.  Please request a new password reset." %}</p>

        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock maincontent %}
```

Comment: when i trace the lib package i understood the fault is occuring because POST form is getting GET in the django.contrib.auth.view why is this happening help me.

Comment: i tried your code but the problem is with GET and POST.Post form is redirected as get.So i cannot save the data in database

Comment: This can't be as the form method is POST, you are doing something else wrong here.

Comment: problem in NoReverseMatch at /password-reset/

Comment: {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}

Comment: does we required to paste email template on the folder

Comment: its worked the problem get solved when added # to the action in html form